# Read file with timestamp as name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file name: `20200925-183744pm.txt`. I am unable to read with following code:

```
file1 = open('(fil2)', '.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines() 
  
count = 0
# Read File line by Line 
for line in Lines: 
    time.sleep(5/10)
    print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
```

Comment: The way you are calling the `open()` function is very odd... Why not `open("20200925-183744pm.txt")`?

Comment: unrelated but..  why `time.sleep(5/10)`?

Comment: `'(fil2)', '.txt'` ->  `f'{fil2}.txt'` ?

Comment: actually I have created a program to get list of folder & files, copy & save all in file with timestamp and re read those again in same program